# Tableau-Generated Query Not Hitting the Optimal Table Index

Tags: t-sql, indexing, ssms, tableau-api, windows-server-2012

I have a tableau-generated query that looks like:

```
SELECT (((DATEPART(year,(CASE
WHEN 0 = ISDATE(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR)) THEN NULL
ELSE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CAST(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR) as datetime)), 0) END)) * 10000) + (DATEPART(month,(CASE
WHEN 0 = ISDATE(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR)) THEN NULL
ELSE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CAST(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR) as datetime)), 0) END)) * 100)) + DATEPART(day,(CASE
WHEN 0 = ISDATE(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR)) THEN NULL
ELSE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CAST(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR) as datetime)), 0) END))) AS [md:M_Date:ok]
FROM [tbl].[table] [table1]
GROUP BY (((DATEPART(year,(CASE
WHEN 0 = ISDATE(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR)) THEN NULL
ELSE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CAST(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR) as datetime)), 0) END)) * 10000) + (DATEPART(month,(CASE
WHEN 0 = ISDATE(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR)) THEN NULL
ELSE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CAST(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR) as datetime)), 0) END)) * 100)) + DATEPART(day,(CASE
WHEN 0 = ISDATE(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR)) THEN NULL
ELSE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CAST(CAST([table1].[M_Date] AS VARCHAR) as datetime)), 0) END)))
```

table 'table' has two indexes:

1. A clustered index over the columns [M_Date], [Team], [Player], [Second].
2. A non-unique, non-clustered index over the columns [Player], [M_Date], [Team]

When I look at the Execution Plan for the query, it tells me that the *second* index is being used. This seems strange to me because I thought that an index could only be used if the columns involved form 'a leftmost prefix of the index' (as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)) which this query does not. If anyone could explain what it is I am not understanding, or if this is just an odd case where the incorrect index is getting used, your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is that the entire query Tableau generated or just part of it?

Comment: I grabbed the query by copying the 'details' field of the process in SQL Server Management Studio's Activity Monitor. I am not sure if it is the entire query or not. I will try to get the person who generated the query to hit the DB again as soon as I can so I can try to get more details/code.